# Not receiving user data from Apple JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple), provided by Apple, I will be able to receive user's full name after successful authorization.

The data I should get:

```
{
     "authorization": {
       "code": "[CODE]",
       "id_token": "[ID_TOKEN]",
       "state": "[STATE]"
     },
     "user": {
       "email": "[EMAIL]",
       "name": {
         "firstName": "[FIRST_NAME]",
         "lastName": "[LAST_NAME]"
       }
     }
}
```

The data I am receiving:

```
{
    "authorization": {
        "code": [CODE],
        "id_token": [TOKEN],
        "state": [DATE]
    },
    "userData": {
        "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
        "aud": [CLIENT ID],
        "exp": 1705410345,
        "iat": 1705323945,
        "sub": "001444.684e7c6273564b439b17498e791080d6.0659",
        "c_hash": "a-ronQDp7RZtub_FJ-pceQ",
        "email": [MY EMAIL],
        "email_verified": "true",
        "auth_time": 1705323945,
        "nonce_supported": true
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no "name" value.

I pass "name email" into scope parameter.

```
nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueAppleLogin, {
      clientId: config.public.appleClientId,
      scope: "name email",
      redirectURI: [REDIRECT URI],
      state: time.toString(),
      usePopup: true,
    });
```

I would be thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: How does the request look like in the console. I see `"scope=name email"`   OR `[SCOPES]` in the documentation

Comment: @mplungjan well, I do not send any requests manually, but apple does in the auth window. My investigations showed that there are no problems with scopes :/